# how to fix tailwindcss min breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on a React project with Tailwind Css and I have a problem with breakpoints. Tailwind by default is mobile responsive and you customize the style for larger screens according to Tailwind media query breakpoints:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| sm | 640px |
| md | 768px |
| lg | 1024px |
| xl | 1280px |
| 2xl | 1536px |

However, if you run the app on mobile, it will take the `lg:` screen style and if you inspect it in the browser with mobile view it will take the `md:` screen style.
Take this code for example:

```html
<div className='text-2xl text-red-500 sm:text-sky-200 md:text-gray-500 lg:text-blue-600'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum molestiae aliquam consequuntur itaque sed exercitationem tempore error explicabo, blanditiis mollitia optio enim dicta a sapiente odio laborum commodi. Delectus, saepe!</p>
</div>
```

Here the text should be red until it reaches 640px, then sky until 768px, and gray until 1024px and then blue.

However, what I get in the browser inspection mobile view is gray on any screen less than 1024px until it reaches 1024px and then it turns blue  and what I get on the mobile itself is blue.

Is there something I am missing here??

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export const content = [
  "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  "./public/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
];
export const theme = {
  extend: {
    colors: {
      'custom1': "#1e1e1e"
    },
    boxShadow: {
      'sm': '0 5px 5px -5px rgba(233, 88, 12, 1)'
    }
  },
};
export const plugins = [
  require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
  require('postcss-import'),
  require('tailwindcss'),
  require('autoprefixer'),
];`
```

I tried to make it mobile responsive.

Comment: Consider checking when you are looking at your browser inspection mobile view, that the viewport is less than `640px` to see the text be red. It seems to work as desired in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ERxGr18MnD) so it seems like there could be some misconfiguration not shown.

Comment: @Wongjn i did that and it's the same thing

Comment: OK, then since it seems to work as desired in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ERxGr18MnD), it seems like there could be some misconfiguration not shown.

Comment: @Wongjn  there isn't am afraid any misconfiguration but i don't know why it doesn't work the same as in the tailwind play??

Comment: I'd assume there is some misconfiguration, but that you have failed to identify it.

Comment: @Wongjn maybe so , then help me identify said misconfiguration

Comment: Sure, please show it so I can identify it

Comment: Solved , i recreated the app from scratch added tailwind  again and everything seems to be working fine now, thanks.